# Waiting for a TThread to finish with WaitForSingleObject()

Tags: multithreading, delphi, waitforsingleobject, tthread

I am creating a thread, and then say want to wait for it to terminate with a WFSO call (simplified pseudo-code below, obviously no one wants to wait on a thread right after creating it).

```
constructor TFileScannerThread.Create(Parameters)
begin
/// assign parameters to private variables, and call
inherited Create(true);  //Create Suspended
FreeOnTerminate := true; 
Start; 
end;
```

In the main thread

```
fst := TFileScannerThread.Create(BaseFolder, ScanMode, AbortEvent);

///  I presume, the next call would block the main thread until the child thread is done
///  but, it seems to create a deadlock & WFSO never returns
///  I get a WAIT_TIMEOUT if I use a finite wait time
WaitForsingleObject(fst.Handle, INFINITE);
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?  If I do not have the WFSO the thread completes in about 10 seconds.

Edit: Creating with FreeOnTerminate=false does not create this issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting ``FreeOnTerminate := false``? Because in the other case the thread handle should become invalid after the thread has terminated!

Comment: @Delphi_corder, you point is correct. The reason why it did not work for me was due to a problem elsewhere (I had a Thread.Synchronize call in the thread. ouch).

Answer (score 8):

Waiting on a `TThread` object that uses `FreeOnTerminate=true` is a race condition, as the object could be freed at *any moment* once its `Execute()` method has exited.  So unless you can *guarantee* that you are calling `WaitForSingleObject()` *before* the thread's `OnTerminate` event is fired, then you are not *guaranteed* to have a valid object on which to read its `Handle` property.  Basically, once the thread's constructor exits, all bets are off when using `FreeOnTerminate=true`, unless you use an `OnTerminate` event handler. `FreeOnTerminate=true` is meant for "create and forget" kind of threads. If you need to refer to a thread for any reason, using `FreeOnTerminate=true` becomes dangerous if you are not *very* careful.

If you are going to wait on a `TThread` object, there is no point on using `FreeOnTerminate=true` on that object, since you can just free the object yourself once the wait is complete.  Doing so ensures the object remains valid until you manually free it, thus you can use its `Handle` at any time:

```pascal
constructor TFileScannerThread.Create(Parameters)
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := false;
  // assign parameters to private variables
end;
```

```pascal
fst := TFileScannerThread.Create(BaseFolder, ScanMode, AbortEvent);
...
WaitForSingleObject(fst.Handle, INFINITE);
fst.Free;
```

<sup>(you don't need to call `Start()` inside the constructor, use `CreateSuspended=False` instead, the thread will not actually begin running until after the constructor exits)</sup>

That being said, it is impossible for `WaitForSingleObject()` to return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` on an `INFINITE` timeout.  But it is possible for it to return `WAIT_FAILED`, such as when the `TThread` object is freed before `WaitForSingleObject()` is called, or even while it is still waiting on the `Handle`, thus closing the `Handle` while it is being used.

With regard to a deadlock, if you have an `OnTerminate` event handler assigned to the `TThread` object, that handler gets called via the `TThread::Synchronize()` method so that the handler runs in the main thread.  But, if the main thread is blocked on `WaitForSingleObject()`, then it can't service any `TThread::Synchronize()` (or `TThread::Queue()`) requests.  Thus, you end up with the worker thread waiting on the main thread while the main thread is waiting on the worker thread - deadlock.

To avoid that, you can call `WaitForSingleObject()` in a loop with a short timeout so that you can call the RTL's [`CheckSynchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) function periodically while you are waiting:

```pascal
var h: THandle;

h := fst.Handle;
while WaitForSingleObject(h, 500) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
  CheckSynchronize;

fst.Free;
```

There are other issues to deal with when using a blocking wait, like `SendMessage()` calls from other threads to the main thread.  So you would need to service those requests as well:

```pascal
var
  h: THandle;
  ret: DWORD;
  msg: TMsg;

h := fst.Handle;
repeat
  case MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, h, False, 1000, QS_SENDMESSAGE) of
    WAIT_OBJECT_0, WAIT_FAILED: Break;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
    WAIT_TIMEOUT: CheckSynchronize;
  end;
until False;

fst.Free;
```

Alternatively, add the [`Classes.SyncEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.SyncEvent) handle to the wait as well (`TThread::Synchronize()` and `TThread::Queue()` signal it internally when there are requests pending):

```pascal
var
  h: array[0..1] of THandle;
  ret: DWORD;
  msg: TMsg;

h[0] := fst.Handle;
h[1] := SyncEvent;
repeat
  case MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2, h, False, INFINITE, QS_SENDMESSAGE) of
    WAIT_OBJECT_0, WAIT_FAILED: Break;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: CheckSynchronize;
    WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2: PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
  end;
until False;

fst.Free;
```

FYI, `TThread` has its own `WaitFor()` method that performs a blocking wait on the thread to terminate, while servicing `TThread::Synchronize()`/`TThread::Queue()` and `SendMessage()` requests, similar to above:

```pascal
fst := TFileScannerThread.Create(BaseFolder, ScanMode, AbortEvent);
...
fst.WaitFor;
fst.Free;
```

Just note that calling `TThread::WaitFor()` on a `TThread` object that uses `FreeOnTerminate=true` is not safe, either.  It will either fail with an `EThread` or `EOSError` exception when the `Handle` is closed between internal loop iterations, or it will likely just crash outright when it tries to access the `Handle` of a `TThread` object that has already been freed.

Comment: I thought I need to set parameters first, before calling the inherited Create, with ```createdsuspended=false```. Did not know that _the **thread will not actually begin running until after the constructor exits**_. How does that work since the constructor is in the main thread, and with ```createsuspended=false``` there is nothing to tell the new thread not to run?

Comment: @Nani The actual thread is started in the `AfterConstruction` method.

Comment: @Nani the behavior you describe was a bug in Delphi 5 and earlier, but was fixed in Delphi 6. [Per the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Create): "*If CreateSuspended is false, Execute is called immediately **after the constructor**.*" The thread is always created as suspended in the base constructor, and then `AfterConstruction()` is overridden to start the thread running if `CreateSuspended=false`. `AfterConstruction()` is called after all constructors have exited.